# Unit Test a method that searches element in db

Tags: asp.net, ajax, unit-testing, c#-4.0, tdd

I wanted to do a Unit Test for a method in the following Class:

```
 public class SearchInfo : IDisposable
        {
            public List<SearchResult> SerialResults { get; set; }
            public List<SearchResult> TagResults { get; set; } 
            /// <summary>
            /// Uses the Search string to filter a resultset by Serial and Tag
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="search"></param>
            public SearchInfo(string search)
            {
                SerialResults = new List<SearchResult>();
                TagResults = new List<SearchResult>();

                SerialResults.AddRange(FindSerial(search));
                TagResults.AddRange(FindTags(search));

            }

            private static IEnumerable<SearchResult> FindTags(string search)
            {

                List<SearchResult> result;
                using (var db = new TIPWebITDataContext())
                {
                    result = (from i in db.tblTechInventories
                              where i.Tag.Equals(search)
                              select new SearchResult()
                                  {
                                      SearchType = "Tag",
                                      Key = i.Tag,
                                      KeyCaption = i.Tag,
                                      Name = i.tblTechItem.ItemName

                                  }).ToList();
                }
                return result;
            }
            private static IEnumerable<SearchResult> FindSerial(string search)
            {
                List<SearchResult> result;
                using (var db = new TIPWebITDataContext())
                {
                    result = (from i in db.tblTechInventories
                              where i.Serial.Contains(search)
                              select new SearchResult()
                              {
                                  SearchType = "Searial",
                                  Key = i.Tag,
                                  KeyCaption = i.Serial,
                                  Name = i.tblTechItem.ItemName

                              }).ToList();
                }
                return result;

            }

            #region Implementation of IDisposable

            public void Dispose()
            {
                SerialResults = null;
                TagResults = null;
            }

            #endregion
        }

        public class SearchResult
        {
            public string SearchType { get; set; }
            public string Key { get; set; }
            public string KeyCaption { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }


    }
```

Note:

Method `Name = FindTags()` returns return result.
The method checks the entered tag is present in database or not. If it is available returns the result.

How will we unit test this method?

Have mocked the Repo
Have covered scenario of "THROWS EXCEPTION"
Question is how to unit test the scenario of ALL WENT WELL ie user;s makeModel matched with repository's makeModel

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, this is an integration test and not a unit test.

With a unit test, you would mock the DB interaction and simple test the logic in your code.

However, I appreciate that it is easier to test in this manner and do so myself. The way to deal with this would be to inject test data into your database that gives a consistent result and assert against that. This test data can be injected in TestSetup and removed if required in TestCleanup.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisBint. Can u please suggest me the code(unit test) for the above code.What i mean, can u produce the TestMethod.